# No matching definition was found for `@family-name:'icons-blank-theme

Tags: magento2.4, magento-upgrade, static-content-deploy, less-compilation

We have upgraded Magento version from 2.3.4 to 2.4.2,
while we execute deploy command we are facing below errors :

```
frontend/Magento/louellabelle/en_GB     3349/3580           ==========================>- 93%    12 secs
Compilation from source: /var/www/vhosts/lbstaging.com/htdocs/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/styles-m.less
No matching definition was found for `@family-name:'icons-blank-theme', @font-path:"../fonts/Blank-Theme-Icons/Blank-Theme-Icons", @font-weight:normal, @font-style:normal, @font-display:block` in _icons.less on line 7, column 5
05| 
06| & when (@media-common = true) {
07|     .lib-font-face(
```

we have also tried adding below code to our custom css :

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'icons-blank-theme';
  src: url('../fonts/Blank-Theme-Icons/Blank-Theme-Icons.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/Blank-Theme-Icons/Blank-Theme-Icons.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

hence we already have the files in the magento base location :

```
pub/static/frontend/Magento/louellabelle_new/en_GB/fonts/Blank-Theme-Icons
```

and

```
vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/fonts/Blank-Theme-Icons
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your .less files with the latest variable added on 2.4.2

Check how variables that show on the di:compile error are setup in vendor for these files :

> _typography.less styles-m.less
>
> email-fonts.less
>
> styles-m.min.css

Update the variables in your design directory when you overrode those files. Run

> rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* pub/static/*
> var/view_preprocessed/*
>
> bin/magento setup:upgrade && bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
> && bin/magento setup:di:compile